# Initialize Tensor Value to 'None'

Tags: tensorflow

I am looking to use rnn.rnn() function and feed the 'state' back to reset the rnn series (as I run a few sequence, what if's in between).  I would like the "state=None" for the first run, ultimately its initialized value as it will not always be feed back to the graph (so it needs to be a variable rather than Placeholder).

```
outputs, stateFINAL = rnn.rnn(cell_L1,Xinputs, initial_state=state, dtype=tf.float32)
```

When needed I capture the stateFINAL and feed it to the "state" variable.  I tried a simple init in the graph as:

```
state=None
```

I am not sure if this is a single Initialization or will set state to None each time the graph is executed.  So I decided to try a Variable initializer like:

```
state = tf.Variable(None,trainable=False,validate_shape=False,dtype=tf.float32)
```

Error returned:

```
ValueError: initial_value must be specified.
```

I am using the latest TensorFlow 0.9.0 RC, and the documentation states if you set validation_shape=False you don't need an initial value.  So I have tried the above line with and without the "None" and neither works.  Is this overkill, did I have it right with the simple state = None?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cell.zero_state() to get an initial zero state.